# SVG path animation from center point

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to animate an SVG that has 3 stages: initial, hover and click. I want to animate all stages from one line. I'm using Snap SVG to get it working.

You can view the working codepen at http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjEeZR 
Please click the red cirkel in the pen

As you see, the path is animated from the top-left corner of the viewbox. The 'click' stage is bigger then the other two stages. So when the click is triggerd, the path is animated downwards.

How can I animate between my path's so that the animation is triggerd from the center point of the viewbox?

Thanks in advance!

html:

```
<a href="#" id="chooseLang" class="hotCornersBtn">
     <svg></svg>
</a>
```

jquery:

```
//SVG-snap
    var none = "none"
        sausRed = "#ff1a29"
        strokeWidth = 3

        chooseLang = Snap("#chooseLang svg");

        initLangSvg = "M21.5,11.5c0,2.8-1.1,5.3-2.9,7.1c-1.8,1.8-4.3,2.9-7.1,2.9c-2.8,0-5.3-1.1-7.1-2.9c-1.8-1.8-2.9-4.3-2.9-7.1c0-2.8,1.1-5.3,2.9-7.1c1.8-1.8,4.3-2.9,7.1-2.9c2.8,0,5.3,1.1,7.1,2.9C20.4,6.2,21.5,8.7,21.5,11.5z"
        hoverLangSvg = "M21.5,13.5c0,2.8-2.1,3.8-4.6,5c-4.7,2.3-3.7,5.7-6.3,7s-8.4,0.8-9.1-3.9c-0.6-4.1,1.1-5.3,1.1-8.1c0-2.8-2.5-4.9-0.1-8.1c1.8-2.3,3.6-3.9,9.1-3.9c5.2,0,4.1,4.2,7,6C20.9,8.8,21.5,10.7,21.5,13.5z"
        clickLangSvg = "M33.1,18.2c1.1,3.9-4.3,8.6-10.6,9.3c-5.4,0.6-1.8,6.9-7.1,8.9c-6.7,2.6-9-0.7-8.5-6c0.5-4.6-9.6-6-3.5-12C6.7,15.3,0.6,10.1,4.9,7c4-2.9,4,7.6,13-4.1c2.7-3.5,11.4-0.1,7.4,8.2C22.4,17.2,31.2,11.6,33.1,18.2z"

        boundingBox = chooseLang.rect(0, 0, 40, 40).attr({fill: none, stroke: none, strokeWidth: none});

        outerCircle = chooseLang.path(initLangSvg).attr({viewBox:"0,0,40,40", preserveAspectRatio:"xMidYMin", fill: none, stroke: sausRed, strokeWidth: strokeWidth});

        boundingBoxGroup = chooseLang.group(outerCircle, boundingBox); 


    function chooseLangInit() {
        outerCircle.animate({d:initLangSvg}, 400);
    }

    function chooseLangHover() {
        outerCircle.animate({d:hoverLangSvg}, 400);
    } 

    function chooseLangClick() {
        outerCircle.animate({d:clickLangSvg}, 400);
    } 


////
$('document').ready(function() {


    //  
    $( "#chooseLang" ).hover(
      function() {
         chooseLangHover(); 
      }, function() {
         chooseLangInit();

      }
    ).click(function() {
        chooseLangClick();
    });



});
```

Comment: Why not just design your paths so that they all have the same centre?

Comment: As Paul says, the sensible thing would be to have all the paths around the same centre. Snap is just interpolating the points on the path, otherwise you have to start animating viewBoxes or transforms once drawn and it can get quite fiddly. If necessary you can use Snap.path.map() to recalculate the path points into a new position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can move the two first paths closer to the center before you animate them, using @Ian's `Snap.path.map()` method:

```
var matrix = new Snap.Matrix();
initLangSvg  = Snap.path.map(initLangSvg, matrix.translate(4,7));
hoverLangSvg = Snap.path.map(hoverLangSvg, matrix.translate(1,-1));
```

Updated pen: http://codepen.io/Sphinxxxx/pen/EPzmgO